Can't change label's text through config() in Python tkinter
I'm trying to wrangle my too big app with too small library and I'm so close. I'm sick of the inadequacies of tk's variables and decided to move around entire widgets as attributes of specialized classes. But the labels don't want to cooperate.
Here's the code:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Interface():
    #zm = [tk.StringVar(self.winfo_toplevel()) for _ in range(6)]
    zm = [ttk.Label() for _ in range(6)]
    

class Main_Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.title("Panel sterowania")
        
        FrameA(self).grid(row=0, column=0)
        FrameB(self).grid(row=1, column=0)


class FrameA(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        ttk.Button(self, text="Butt", command=self.butt_fun
                   ).grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    
    def butt_fun(self):
        for i, lb in enumerate(Interface.zm):
            lb.config(text = str(i))


class FrameB(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(tuple([i for i in range(6)]), weight=1)
        
        for i, lb in enumerate(Interface.zm):
            lb = ttk.Label(self, text='A')
            lb.grid(row=0, column=i)


def close(root):
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()


def main():
    w = Main_Window()
    w.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: close(w))
    w.mainloop()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The labels should change from 'A' to the number of their column after pressing a button "Butt".

You know that the Labels you create in FrameB never get written to Interface.zm? Also FrameA.butt_fun changes the text on the labels in Interface.zm that are never shown on the screen.

@TheLizzard That's true, and fixing that helped. Thanks.
